# Offering only https version of a website

Tags: http, https

Good day!

Suppose you run an international website with visitors from the whole world. Is there any risk in offering only the https version of it (e. g. maybe some countries don't allow https protocol? Or some application through which the website or web services can be reached don't allow that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A secure connection over https may be blocked for security, surveillance or censorship. Some sites may totally be blocked, and sometimes only https requests are prohibited (meaning http / clear-text still works).

Actors blocking connections may be the following :

- Network Administration (companies may block some connections)
- ISP Restriction
- Governement Restrictions (e.g. North Korea, China, Iran etc.)

**Either case is pretty rare, and you'll have more advantages serving your site over https.** The question is whether your site does serve content that may not please one or more actors of the above list. If it does, you need to evaluate if you can run the business without the clients being blocked (who still may access your website through a VPN or Tor).

When setting up your https version, inspect your implementation with these two awesome tools :

- https://observatory.mozilla.org
- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide a list of Governement Restrictions for http? I did not find any online.

Comment: @Fabbio Wikipedia has a list of countries blocking content : [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_and_surveillance_by_country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_and_surveillance_by_country).

If you go down the list, you see a whole lot of countries operating censorship and surveillance, and Wikipedia has precisions for each country it cites, like China ( [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China) ), where many common sites are blocked.